# C client/server socket error

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, client

I'm writing a basic chat program in C. I've built the framework for it but I can't proceed further until I fix the username error I'm getting. My client and server are communicating but when I input my username, The server displays the previously entered username.

EX: client program enters Joe: server doesn't display anything

client program enters Tom: server displays "Username entered: Joe"

client program enters Rob: server displays "Username entered: Tom"

This is the client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096
//void leave(int sig); /* Things to do after signal handler is called*/ 

void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}

/*Routine to send data*/ 
static void *do_send(void *arg) 
{ 
int fd = *(int*)(arg); //Socket File Descriptor
char payload[512];
for(; ;) { 

    scanf("%s\r\n\n", payload);
    write(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));

    //Choose an available client’s username and send it to the server 
    //if ( the peer is ready to chat) 
    //for(; ;) {
        //Code to send msg to its peer  
    //}
}
pthread_exit((void *)0); 
}

/*Routine to receive data*/ 
static void *do_recv(void *arg) 
{

int fd = *(int*)(arg);
char payload[512];
for(; ;) { 
    //Code to receive data 
    read(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));
    //Print data 
    printf("%s\n", payload);
} 
pthread_exit((void *)0); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
//Declare variables
int sockfd, n;
char recvline[MAXLINE+1];
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
int status;
pthread_t chld_thr1, chld_thr2;

//Create socket. 
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    error("Socket error");
}

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(1024);
//Send a connection request to server 
if(connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
{
    error("Connect error");
}
//Register username
/* Create a thread to send data */ 
pthread_create(&chld_thr1, NULL, do_send, (void *)&sockfd);
/* Create a thread to receive data */ 
pthread_create(&chld_thr2, NULL, do_recv, (void *)&sockfd);
//pthread_join(do_send, NULL);
//Close connection and exit

//Loops so program doesn't close
for(; ;){

}
}
```

This is the server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Function prototypes and global variables */

#define SA  struct sockaddr
#define LISTENQ 1024

/*Function executed by the new thread */
static void *do_child(void *arg) 
{
//Declare variables 
int fd = *(int*)(arg); //Socket Descriptor
char payload[512];
int list = 1;
int chat = 2;
int exit = 3;
int bytesRead = 0;

//Initial verification and registration codes
strcpy(payload, "Please enter your username:"); 
write(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));

for(; ;) {
    //Receive messages from client 
    //Code to receive data 
    bytesRead = read(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));
    //Print data
    if (bytesRead > 0){
        printf("Username entered: %s\n", payload);
    }

    //Check the msg_type of the message
    //if(m1.msg_type == list)
        //Send the list of available clients 
    //if(m1.msg_type ==chat)
        //Forward messages to the peer that a client wants to chat with you 
        //if(m1.msg_type == chatMessage)
        //Forward messages to its peer
    //if(m1.msg_type == exit) 

        //Remove the client from the client list. Close the client connection
}
pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//Declare Variables
int listenfd, connfd; //Socket ID's
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
pthread_t chld_thr;
char payload[512];

//Create Socket
listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

servaddr.sin_port = htons(1024);

//Bind to the Address and Port Number Pair
bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

//Listen
listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

for(; ;) {
   connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA *) NULL, NULL);
   if (connfd > 0){
        strcpy(payload, "Connection Accepted");
        printf("%s\n", payload);

        /*Create a new thread to handle the connections. */ 
        pthread_create(&chld_thr, NULL, do_child, (void *)&connfd);
    }
    else
        printf("%s\n", "No connection could be made.");
} 
//Close listen connection and exit.
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition between `accept` and `int fd = *(int*)(arg);`. If the `accept` completes before the thread can dereference the pointer you passed it, you will wind up with two threads reading from the same socket.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have never encountered a race condition or needed to debug one. Any tips on how to do so for this scenario?

Comment: Don't pass a thread a pointer to a value that's used by other threads. Instead, either pass them the value or allocate a copy of the value, pass them a pointer to it, and have them de-allocate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple....

Change:
    scanf("%s\r\n\n", payload);

to:
    scanf("%s", payload);

Answer (score 1):

If the protocol is "you always send and receive 512 bytes", then you need to replace this:

```
bytesRead = read(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));
```

and this:

```
read(fd, payload, sizeof(payload));
```

With this:

```
bytesRead = 0;
do
{
   ssize_t j = read(fd, payload + bytesRead, 512 - bytesRead));
   if (j <= 0)
   {
       bytesRead = -1;
       break;
   }
   bytesRead += j;
} while (bytesRead < 512);
```

If that's not the protocol, then what is it?

I'm presuming you don't care about security. But if you do, you need to consider the possibility that the 512 bytes sent may not contain a terminator.

See also my comment about your race condition between `accept` and the thread copying its parameter.

Comment: VG but you don't want to set bytesRead to -1, you want to leave it alone, maybe unless there was an error. You want whatever *was* read to be available after the loop.

Comment: @EJP My assumption is that his protocol is "you must write/read 512 bytes". Fewer than 512 bytes would constitute an incomprehensible, partial message. The point of this code is to implement that protocol specifically.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can read/write any length message according to my instructions. do i replace every single bytesRead and read function in both the client and server?

Comment: To be clear, every message does not have to be 512 bites. that's just the maximum size

Comment: @BartoshSudak Then you need to design a more complex protocol. How will the recipient know whether they have a complete message if they received fewer than 512 bytes?